# Conditional Probability and updating probabilities

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

My question reads:

A new light bulb has a $15$% chance of lasting up to a month, a $20$% chance of lasting more than a month but less than a year, and a $65$% chance of lasting more than a year. If my bulb is still on after 1 month since I bought it, what is the probability that it will last more than a year?

I have been stuck on this problem for days and I only have a guess of how to approach the problem. I see this is a conditional probability and that we have 3 alternatives but I am not too sure if I would be using Bayes formula at some point. I am having issues with how to use just these three probabilities given and nothing more. Anyone have suggestions? I am also considering the fact that maybe there is some overlap between the probabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the probability it will last more that a year given that it lasted more than a month which is a conditional probability. Let's call the events $Y$ and $M$, so you want $P(Y|M)$. You can indeed use Bayes $$P(Y|M) = \frac{P(M|Y)P(Y)}{P(M)}.$$ The probability it lasted more than a month given that it lasted more than a year is $P(M|Y) = 1$ since it automatically lasts more than a month if it lasts a year. And you already know (or can easily get) $P(Y)$ and $P(M)$ (i.e. the probability that it lasts more than a year and the probability that it lasts more than a month).

Comment: Okay then I was on the right track,thank you. I was thinking 1 was right but it seemed almost too straightforward. Also P(Y) and P(M) I see are given in the problem so I can do the rest. Actually for P(M) would I need to calculate it?

Comment: @Sam $P(M)$ the probability it lasts more than a month, which is not literally one of the numbers given in the problem but is straightforward to calculate from them.

Comment: @Sam yes that's it